# sql injection in ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand these bugs in mysql:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62755

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60808

so i create a sequences inside table :

```
mysql> select id from test_injection ;
```

result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
|  1 |
|  1 |
|  1 |
|  1 |
|  0 |
+----+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and i also try to make the bug above , by using select + agregate function with group by

```
mysql> select count(*),id from test_injection group by id ;
```

result:

```
+----------+----+
| count(*) | id |
+----------+----+
|        2 |  0 |
|        4 |  1 |
+----------+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i try alot of times but no bugs happend .

so i try to use their payload in bug above :

```
mysql> select count(*),floor(rand(0)*2) from security.users ;
```

result:

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key ''

so why the error happen in the second select ? as i i know the duplicate error happen in update/insert queries not in select .

Answer (score 0):

i search a lot on internet for someone can explain this to me , and i fount this happen only in insert/update queries , so when we generate an sequences and do an aggregate function on it , this will insert the sequences in a temp group by table and then do an aggregate function , so this make the error .