# What does <group Key> mean in group by statement?

Tags: mysql

i have made an error today by using this statement :

```
mysql> select count(*),(floor(rand(0)*2))a from security.users group by a ;
```

and the result is :

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0security' for key ' << group_key >'

dont care about the query above , all i need to know is what is exactly the

> << group key>

if its a table , does it accept  only allows unique values ?

Comment: That's what you get when you insert data that violates a primary or unique key and `<< group_key >` should be the name of the key (`PRIMARY`, `unique_email`...). I have no idea why you get that in a `SELECT` query.

Comment: *"I have no idea why you get that in a SELECT query. "* ... Well @ÁlvaroGonzález it can be a bug  -> https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62755  when used in combination with `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález , i dont insert data here , i just use select .

Comment: @RaymondNijland , you are right , i try to understand the bug , can you help me with this ? why i just got that error , and i dont insert/update in a table . i just use an select statement .

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as it is not 100% clear what you are trying to do here..

Comment: @RaymondNijland , can you see my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645828/sql-injection-in-error-1062-23000-duplicate-entry/58662414#58662414

Comment: Also that does not help really well atleast the error is reproducible -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dWYP8fJAdjUran3rJb9yxD/1 ... your link still does not explain which results your are after and what you are trying to do..

Comment: But i think you want something like -> `select
   count(*)
  ,(floor(rand(1)*2))
from
  test_injection
group by
 (floor(rand(1)*2)); `  ... see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dWYP8fJAdjUran3rJb9yxD/6)

Comment: Still a wierd case using a random function like that in a `GROUP BY` to define a group, Because i am not sure why `rand(0)` gives that error and `rand(1)` not .. Something very wierd is happening in the optimizer somewhere .. Because the results from both are the same -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dWYP8fJAdjUran3rJb9yxD/5 .. Consider thinking a other method that not uses a random function in the `GROUP BY`..  Like i asked before provide example data and matching expected results then we know better what you are trying for now this and that other question is simply unclear..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `group by` in my sql query, You need to insert that column into the `SELECT` part of the query as well.